# RMAN backup of RAC database failing

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery, oracle-12c, rman

Backup goes through if I don’t have any explicit connection to any instance :

```
RUN {
ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch1 TYPE DISK FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH00_%U';
ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch2 TYPE DISK FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH01_%U';
ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch3 TYPE DISK FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH02_%U';
ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch4 TYPE DISK FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH03_%U';
Backup incremental level 0 database;
RELEASE CHANNEL ch1;
RELEASE CHANNEL ch2;
RELEASE CHANNEL ch3;
RELEASE CHANNEL ch4;
}
```

But it fails when I specify explicitly the instance name :

```
RMAN> RUN {
2> ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch00 TYPE DISK connect 'sys/oracle@realdb_1' FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH00_%U';
3> ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch01 TYPE DISK connect 'sys/oracle@realdb_2' FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH01_%U';
4> ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch02 TYPE DISK connect 'sys/oracle@realdb_3' FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH02_%U';
5> ALLOCATE CHANNEL ch03 TYPE DISK connect 'sys/oracle@realdb_4' FORMAT '\\192.168.2.11\test\DF_CH03_%U';
6> Backup incremental level 0 database;
7> RELEASE CHANNEL ch00;
8> RELEASE CHANNEL ch01;
9> RELEASE CHANNEL ch02;
10> RELEASE CHANNEL ch03;
11> }
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-12001: could not open channel ch00
RMAN-10008: could not create channel context
RMAN-10003: unable to connect to target database
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you checked that your tns service is working properly? according to the error message displayed in your post shows that there is problem with TNS name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to tnsping realdb_1, realdb_2 individually?

If you're using SCAN, but haven't manually added node specific entries to your tnsnames.ora, this problem is likely to occur upon requesting connection to a specific node, since SCAN may be configured to resolve to the service_name of the RAC, rather than to the "instance_name".

Here's my tnsnames.ora:

```
USAPROJ =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac-scan.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = usaproj.localdomain)
    )
  )

USAPROJ1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = rac-scan.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = usaproj.localdomain)
      (INSTANCE_NAME = usaproj1)   <-------
        )
  )
```

I created another entry, usaproj1, and in addition to service_name parameter, I added "instance_name", to specify the node I wanted to connect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: which netca should i be configuring in? the GRID or DB ? I tried the above and it doesnt seem to work and getting the same issue. Any other methodology to acheive the same. Also what are the steps required on all nodes from netca perspective ?

Comment: used the ORAhome instead of GRID HOME and was able to do this with the above suggestion!

Comment: I am currently faced with an issue for which i have opened another thread. Please help if you can  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120815/unable-to-connect-to-specific-instance-oracle-rac